# list item div isn't going 100% width of parent

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add text on top of an image, I have a `list-item` which contains the image and the div text-block, presumably if I would set the text-block to `width:100%` it should be the same width of the li yet its expanding to the very outer parent.

code: https://jsfiddle.net/wbbgjthe/

```css
#button-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-top: 33vh;
  margin-left: 50vw;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 90vw;
  height: 56vh;
  align-items: center;
}

#button-container li {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

#button-container .text-block {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  top: 200px;
  left: 133px;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<ul id="button-container">
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img class="htmllogo" src="https://psdf.org.pk/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/default-placeholder-300x300.png">
      <div class="text-block">
        <h2>HTML</h2>
        <p>My web projects</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img class="csharplogo" src="https://psdf.org.pk/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/default-placeholder-300x300.png"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can I please know what is the purpose of using position absolute in your element? You are removing the element from the document flow by doing that.

Comment: Likely a bad habit+ majority of tutorials seemed to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that:

> The top, right, bottom, and left properties [of an absolutely positioned element] specify offsets from the edges of the element's *containing block*.
>   -- [position @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

... and ...

> If the position property is absolute, the *containing block* is formed by the edge of the padding box of the nearest ancestor element that has a **position value other than static (fixed, absolute, relative, or sticky)**.
>   -- [Identifying the containing block @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Containing_block#Identifying_the_containing_block)

Since you want to position `.text-block` relative to `<li>`, set `position:relative` on `<li>` to define them as containing blocks for `.text-block`.

---

I also removed `left:133px`, as it is no longer necessary. `Left` will default to `auto` which, in your context, will place it at the left edge of the containing `<li>`.

I also added `box-sizing:border-box` to `.text-block` so that `width` will incorporate `border`.

> `border-box` tells the browser to account for any border and padding in the values you specify for an element's width and height. If you set an element's width to 100 pixels, that 100 pixels will include any border or padding you added, and the content box will shrink to absorb that extra width. This typically makes it much easier to size elements.
>   -- [box-sizing @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).

---

```css
#button-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-top: 33vh;
  margin-left: 50vw;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 90vw;
  height: 56vh;
  align-items: center;
}

#button-container li {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

#button-container .text-block {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  top: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<ul id="button-container">
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img class="htmllogo" src="https://psdf.org.pk/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/default-placeholder-300x300.png">
      <div class="text-block">
        <h2>HTML</h2>
        <p>My web projects</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img class="csharplogo" src="https://psdf.org.pk/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/default-placeholder-300x300.png"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `position:relative` to your `li` elements so that the absolutely-positioned `text-block` is [positioned relative to it.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)  Currently it's being absolutely-positioned relative to the `body`.

```
#button-container li {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: relative; /* add this */
}
```